# How do I add a NSOutlineViewDataSource to my NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview

I am writing a System Preference pane for Mac OS X in Objective-C. The panel includes a `NSOutlineView` bound to a properly configured `NSTreeController`. I also added a delegate class for my `OutlineView` in which I defined my own `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` method.

[image]

When I add new objects to the Tree Controller everything works fine, but now I want to enable [persistence for expanded items](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsoutlineview/1530638-autosaveexpandeditems?language=objc). To do so I need to implement [outlineView:itemForPersistentObject:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsoutlineviewdatasource/1533602-outlineview?language=objc) and [outlineView:persistentObjectForItem:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsoutlineviewdatasource/1532545-outlineview?language=objc) in a data source for the OutlineView, otherwise I get the error:

> *** NSOutlineView data source ((null)) does not implement outlineView:persistentObjectForItem:

How do I do that given my current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate and data source can be the same object. Implement the methods in `OutlineViewDelegate` and connect the data source the the same object as the delegate.

Comment: I had already tried that before posting, but for some reason the items of my outline view would no longer show up.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it's working now. I must have been doing some other mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare that class (the class that is providing the data) as the NSOutlineViewDataSource? Something along these lines:

`@interface YourClass : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOpenSavePanelDelegate>`

*The other declarations are just examples, in this particular case the YourClass inherits from several other ones.

After you declare this you can either use bindings or you can manually connect the data source to your outlineView.

Comment: I didn't, but now I added `<NSOutlineViewDataSource>` to the class `myNode` and defined the two methods in its implementation.  Then I created a new Object of class `myNode` in Interface Builder and set it up as content for the OutlineView. That seems to do the trick. I'll keep working on it and mark the answer as correct if that's the case.